# Wordpress keeps getting into maintenance mode

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, updates

I had already deactivated all plugins automatic updates and core update but it keeps happening once a day even having nothing to update.

I already have

```
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false )
```

in my wp-config.php.

Comment: Hello, if I'm not mistaken, are you stuck in maintenance mode?! If this is the case, enter the host and the public_html folder and delete the .maintenance file. This file is hidden. You must activate the hidden display mode from the host.

Comment: hi @mehdieybakabadi! That's what I use to do but this is not a solution for the problem since it keeps happening all the time. The problem in my case is: I can't have any downtime (even if I just need to remove the file, I still have a 3 - 5minutes downtime between noticing it to removing it).

Comment: Oh, this requires a review of the entire wordpress, and most importantly, the wordpress code